# Assembly resolution fails for dlls in work directory after upgrading to .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

I am upgrading a program from .NET Framework to .NET 6 and have stumbled upon an issue with assembly loading.

The program is plugin-based with plugin dlls residing in a subfolder of the main folder (the main folder is the working directory of the program). The "core" projects and external dependencies reside in the main folder.

The main folder looks like this:

```
|-- Program.exe
|-- Utilities.dll
|-- ExternalDependency.dll
|-- plugins
    |-- Plugin.dll
```

Here, ExternalDependency.dll is a dependency of Plugin.dll. The files are copied into this folder structure by a post-build script.

On starting Program.exe, the program loads all dlls in the "plugins" folder. On loading Plugin.dll, the program fails to locate ExternalDependency.dll.

I expect the program to look in the current working directory for the dll. I have confirmed that the working directory is indeed the directory containing ExternalDependency.dll.

If I place ExternalDependency.dll in the plugins folder, it does indeed load correctly. I don't want to to this as I would have to place everything in the same folder in that case (core projects, plugins and external dependencies), which would mess up plugin loading .

I can also attach my own method to resolve the assembly:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
```

In this case, I am able to load the assembly, even just by calling

```
private Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    return Assembly.LoadFrom(args.Name.Split(',')[0] + ".dll")
}
```

, which, I suppose, just looks in the current working directory.

Even so, it doesn't seem right to implement my own assembly resolution logic to locate a dll in the working directory. This method seems to hook onto other "failures" as well, specifically with locale-specific resource assemblies that otherwise succeed, probably by some other fallback mechanism.

This used to work on .NET Framework and I can't imagine why it would not work on .NET 6. Is the current working directory not an obvious place to look for assemblies? Is there some configuration file somewhere that controls this? Am I missing something else?

Edit: I should note that most dependencies (several of which follow the same location pattern) are loaded correctly, so this seems to be a problem with just one instance.

Comment: Try and use the `ProcessMonitor.exe` to see what is going on. You can find it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: @PaulSinnema Thank you, that's a neat tool that I didn't know about.
I can see that it looks for ExternalDependency.dll in the \plugins folder and doesn't find it, and that it successfully looks for lots of other dlls both in the main folder and in \plugins

Comment: You gave the answer. If I read you correctly: `I can see that it looks for ExternalDependency.dll in the \plugins folder`. The dll is not in that folder.

Comment: @PaulSinnema Sure, I'd just like to understand why it looks there and most importantly, how to make it look in the main folder (which it seems to do correctly for other dependencies), preferably without using AsssemblyResolve

Comment: I think it is because it looks in the same directory your `plugin.dll` is in and subfolders of that folder. Not up. Maybe you should reconsider the directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

This probably is related to assembly probing change in .NETCore. For example, `main_process.dll` has a dependency dll `externaldependency.dll` in its subfolder.

If so, you may need to add `additionalAssemblyPaths` in `main_process.runtimeconfig.json`

```
"additionalAssemblyPaths" : [
      "subfolder_name"
    ],
```

then add path in `main_process.deps.json`

```
  "libraries": {
    "externaldependency": {
      "path": "."
    },
```

Then `main_process` can find `externaldependency.dll` in its subfolder `subfolder_name` in the runtime.

---

Edit:
`subfolder_name` could be `..` which will look up in the parent folder.